# Search option just as that provided in drupal.org

Tags: search

can you please tell me which module to use to provide search options just as the search provided in https://drupal.org/download

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Facetapi](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi) module will help you. From [facetapi](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi) module page:

> The Facet API module allows site builders to easily create and manage
>   faceted search interfaces.

You may also look into [search_api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module. From module page:

> This module provides a framework for easily creating searches on any
>   entity known to Drupal, using any kind of search engine. For site
>   administrators, it is a great alternative to other search solutions,
>   since it already incorporates facetting support and the ability to use
>   the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module for displaying search results, filters, etc.

If you do not want to use the default Drupal search you can use [apachesolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) search module. This module can also be integrated with [facetapi](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi) module.

Answer (score 2):

It's Solr filters. If you don't setup it, you can just use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) Exposed Filters - simplest way.

Other solution - [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) - that have count of integrations for expanding search page.